# How in SQL search and get count for huge table (where-in)

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, where-in

I have sql table:

```
id  user    city
1   Alisa   New York
2   Alisa   Sydney
3   Alisa   Rom
4   Alisa   Toronto
5   Bob     Rom
6   Bob     Moskow
7   Bob     Sydney
8   Tom     Sydney
```

And I need get how many same cities have other users for Bob for example.

```
SELECT user, count(DISTINCT city) FROM table WHERE city IN (
   SELECT city FROM table WHERE user = 'Bob'
) AND user != 'Bob' GROUP BY user
```

and result is:

```
user    count(DISTINCT city)
Alisa   2
Tom     1
```

Do you know other best way to make this request?
Is it ok for huge table?

Comment: I have 8205091 rows, and this sql request took: 1 min 59.27 sec

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
SELECT A.user, 
       count(DISTINCT A.city)
FROM table  A,
     (SELECT city FROM table WHERE user = 'Bob') B
WHERE A.city = B.city
AND A.user != 'Bob'
GROUP BY A.user
```

Comment: This solution is the same @Christos Paisios solution because Temporary B view is run once.

Comment: 24.55 sec its faster :)

Comment: Glad to hear this is faster.

Answer (score 1):

You should pump in some data, then do an  [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html)

That is the only way to predict with reasonable accuracy if it is 'OK'.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Cities (city varchar(100)); 
INSERT INTO Cities SELECT city FROM table WHERE user = 'Bob';

SELECT user, count(DISTINCT t.city) 
FROM table AS t
INNER JOIN Cities AS c ON t.City=c.City
AND t.user !='Bob'
GROUP BY User
```

You could create a temporary table, in which you will store the cities, in which Bob was and then do an inner join between your table and the temporary table you created.

Comment: 44.76 sec, it's not best way :(

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a self join or with `EXISTS`, both of which would be far superior to trying to use `IN (SELECT ...)` which is never a good idea. Whether this is "ok for a huge table" depends on your definition of "ok" and "huge table", along with your schema, but this should at least help point you in the right direction.

Here's the `EXISTS` version:

```
SELECT user, count(DISTINCT city) 
FROM table as main_query
WHERE user != 'Bob' 
AND EXISTS (
  SELECT NULL 
  FROM table as sub_query 
  WHERE sub_query.user = 'Bob' 
  and sub_query.city = main_query.city
)
GROUP BY user
```

Comment: Do you have indexes on the table? If not, try creating an index on city and user.